# Visual Studio 2015 debugging slow to load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Just suddenly over the past day I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2015 where it takes an age to start debugging anything. Even a simple console application with one line will take over 3 minutes just to start. Running without debugging is normal.

Things I've tried:

- Enable Just My Code checked under General Debugging options
- Created local cache of Symbols
- Removed all Breakpoints
- Deleted all user temp files
- Reinstalled Visual Sudio

Nothing has had any effect. When starting debugging it just hangs and VS becomes unresponsive for a couple of minutes until it then will start debugging. Once running it is fine. I don't understand why this has suddenly just started happening.

My company have recently pushed McAfee out to all machines, but this has been running on mine for a while now without any issue so not sure why it would suddenly be causing this now. Has anyone else experienced this and if so how did you fix it?

Comment: Have you applied all updates? Do you connect to source control? Is the code stored on a shared drive? (Local drive is better)

Comment: All up-to-date and code is on local drive. I am connected to VSTS but this occurs on projects outside of source control as well.

Comment: You should try and run without connection to source control, McAfee might mess with the files..

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled Just my code and disabled also diagnostic tools during debug in Tools->settings->debug

Comment: Thanks but I've tried with those settings on and off and it makes no difference for me.